# Is there any way to connect Mysql server independent of version of Mysql to vb.net application?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have developed vb.net application which used to manipulate or process data from Mysql database.
But My question here is there any way to connect mysql db to vb.net application independent of Mysql version compatibility,
For example If i developed my vb.net application to get connected with Mysql 8.0.18 and my client still using MySQL 8.0.13. So my vb.net application should work even with different minor builds of Mysql server 
I dont want to rechange the code all time until unless there any major changes in Mysqlserver

Answer (score 0):

You would only have to change the code if you used features available in the later version that are not in the earlier version.  In minor builds, there will be little of that, if any.  Just use functionality that is available in all version that you want to support and you'll be fine.

If you use Connector/Net as your ADO.NET provider, ensure that you use one that supports all versions you need to be able to connect to.  If there is no such version then you may have to use OLE DB or ODBC.

Comment: It is helpful information. I am also about to design like developing dynamic option to the user who can choose his own Mysql version from application settings. Like i used SQL WorkBench J which has this option to use dynamic connector to the version.